# Couldn't find index page for 'stackless_installer_c4_win32' (maybe misspelled?)

Tags: python, pip, python-stackless

I am trying to install stackless python. I have tried

```
pip install stackless-python
easy_install stackless-python
python -m pip install stackless-python
```

I have done all these and also the same with an underscore instead of a dash.

All of these spit out this:

```
Collecting stackless-python
  Using cached stackless-python-10.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Couldn't find index page for 'stackless_installer_C4_win32' (maybe misspelle
d?)
    No local packages or download links found for stackless_installer_C4_win32<3
.5.2,>=3.5.1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ys5xi1aa\stackless-pytho
n\setup.py", line 158, in <module>
        license='Apache License, Version 2.0',
      File "d:\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in
setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "d:\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py"
, line 269, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "d:\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py"
, line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "d:\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__ini
t__.py", line 826, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "d:\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__ini
t__.py", line 1092, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "d:\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__ini
t__.py", line 1104, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "d:\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py"
, line 380, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "d:\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\
easy_install.py", line 634, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Re
quirement.parse('stackless_installer_C4_win32<3.5.2,>=3.5.1')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Jacob\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ys5xi1aa\stackless-python\
```

I have run these as well

```
pip install -U Distribute
pip install -U setuptools
```

and everything is up to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some similar issues myself. I ended up getting MSI package from [here](https://bitbucket.org/stackless-dev/stackless/wiki/Download) and it installed and works perfectly.